# Disable .dll use for application without Sandboxie

Tags: dll, operating-system, exe

I need to use old program that automatically load system rsaenh.dll (and other) file when it starts. Maybe this .dll file is changed in Windows Vista or something, but this application stopped working in Vista+ OS. Using the Sandboxie program, I can disable access to .dll for this application, and it works correctly.

Please, if anyone know, tell me how to disable access to this .dll file in application .exe file without Sandboxie?